# Need clarification, why the wrapper methods? Ruby on Rails Tutorial chapter 9 section 9.3.3 current-user -

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, helper

I understand that the helpers are not generally accessible in controllers.  But why all the wrapping around a instance variable @current_user?

Why does the helper have "current_user=" and "current_user" defined as methods?  Why can @current_user be all that is needed for this section?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to continue reading.  From the text:

> If we did this, we would effectively replicate the functionality of attr_accessor, first seen in Section 4.4.5 and used to make the virtual password attribute in Section 7.1.1.8 The problem is that it utterly fails to solve our problem: with the code in Listing 9.15, the user’s signin status would be forgotten: as soon as the user went to another page—poof!—the session would end and the user would be automatically signed out.
>
> To avoid this problem, we can find the session user corresponding the cookie...

Answer (score 0):

I did get a good answer from a co-worker.

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
    self.current_user = user   
  end 
end

def current_user
    @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
end
```

It is a refactor issue.  You don't want to replicate the code from current user everywhere.

I still think the `current_user=` method is not needed. I don't see a reason not to use the instance variable for assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question. Yes, I think that current_user is structured this way to prevent code replication. But I also think it might be a syntax issue. If you made current_user a public property of `SessionHelper`, (I think) you'd access it with `SessionHelper.current_user`, but if you define a `current_user` method, and a `current_user=(user)` method, you can use the `current_user` property without the extra clutter.

So, I think it's just a style issue. Your approach works fine too.

Comment: Thanks for the code highlights @Mab879. Still getting the hang of the site.